# rearrange a variable based on another variable

Tags: r

Data:

```
set.seed(25)
df<- data.frame(rank=round(rnorm(10)),category=round(runif(10)),v=round(rnorm(10)))

   rank category  v
1     0        0  1
2    -1        0 -1
3    -1        0  1
4     0        0  2
5    -2        0 -1
6     0        0  1
7     2        0  0
8     1        1  0
9     0        1  2
10    0        0 -2
```

I want the variable "v" follows the same ranking as the variable "rank1", within each category. My question is how could I create the desired variable "v1"?

Desired output:

```
df <- transform(df, rank1 = ave(v, category, FUN = function(x) rank(x, ties.method = "random")))

   rank category  v rank1  v1
1     0        0  1     6 -1
2    -1        0 -1     3  1
3    -1        0  1     7 -1
4     0        0  2     8 -2
5    -2        0 -1     2  1
6     0        0  1     5  0
7     2        0  0     4  1
8     1        1  0     1  2
9     0        1  2     2  0
10    0        0 -2     1  2
```

Comment: I have no idea how you're getting your output. Maybe try simplifying your example and providing some more explanation into why the desired output is what you say it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I get the desired result:

```
set.seed(25)
df <- data.frame(rank=round(rnorm(10)), category=round(runif(10)), v=round(rnorm(10)))
df <- transform(df, rank1 = ave(v, category, FUN = function(x) rank(x, ties.method = "random")))

df$v1 <- NA

for (i in unique(df$category)) {
  df$v1[df$category==i] <- sort(df$v[df$category==i], decrea=TRUE)[df$rank1[df$category==i]]
}
```

The idea is going through the categories and apply the order given by `rank1` to the **sorted** part of the vector `v`.